MockedProvider doesn't switch mocks in different tests
I'm using vitest for my test runner and I have a custom renderer for my test:
// setupTests.ts

import { MockedProvider, MockedResponse } from '@apollo/client/testing';
import { render as rtlRender } from '@testing-library/react';
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

function render(
  ui: string | number | boolean | Iterable<ReactNode> | JSX.Element | null | undefined,
  {
    locale = LanguageEnum.En,
    mocks,
    ...renderOptions
  }: {
    locale?: LanguageEnum;
    mocks?: MockedResponse<any, any>[] | undefined;
  } = {}
) {
  function Wrapper({ children }) {
    return (
      <MockedProvider mocks={mocks}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={loadMessages(locale)}>
            {children}
          </IntlProvider>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </MockedProvider>
    );
  }
  return rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions });
}

I'm trying test my query that uses useQuery from apollo-graphql. My component is a tab that essentially fetches data when the tabs are switched. Everything works fine until I switch the tab and I use a different mock passed into the MockProvider. Here is my test:
// ChallengePage.test.tsx

const now = DateTime.now().startOf('day').toISO();

const activeFilterMock = [
  {
    request: {
      query: FetchUserChallengesDocument,
      reuse: 1,
      variables: {
        filters: [
          [{ relationship: 'challenge', column: 'start_at', operator: 'lt', value: now }],
          [{ relationship: 'challenge', column: 'end_at', operator: 'gt', value: now }],
        ],
      },
    },
    result: {
      data: {
        userChallenges: aUserChallenges(),
      },
    },
  },
];

const upcomingFilterMock = [
  {
    request: {
      query: FetchUserChallengesDocument,
      reuse: 1,
      variables: {
        filters: [[{ relationship: 'challenge', column: 'start_at', operator: 'gt', value: now }]],
      },
      result: {
        data: {
          // create user challenges that are in the future by maximum 10 days
          userChallenges: {
            data: [
              aUserChallenge({
                challenge: aChallenge({ startAt: faker.date.future() }),
              }),
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
];

escribe('ChallengePage', () => {
  describe('Active Tab', () => {
    it('should start on the active tab', async () => {
      const { container } = render(<ChallengePage />, {
        mocks: activeFilterMock,
      });

      expect(getByRole(container, 'tab', { name: 'Active' })).toHaveAttribute(
        'aria-selected',
        'true'
      );
    });

    it('should render a skeleton loading state', async () => {
      const { container } = render(<ChallengePage />, {
        mocks: activeFilterMock,
      });

      // Check is skeleton is rendered
      expect(container).toContainHTML('ant-skeleton');
    });

    it('should render a list of challenges', async () => {
      render(<ChallengePage />, {
        mocks: activeFilterMock,
      });

      await waitFor(() => {
        expect(screen.getByTestId('active-challenge')).toBeInTheDocument();
      });
    });
  });

  describe('Upcoming Tab', () => {
    it('should switch to the upcoming tab', async () => {
      const { container } = render(<ChallengePage />, {
        mocks: upcomingFilterMock,
      });

      act(() => {
        fireEvent.click(getByRole(container, 'tab', { name: 'Upcoming' }));
      });

      expect(getByRole(container, 'tab', { name: 'Upcoming' })).toHaveAttribute(
        'aria-selected',
        'true'
      );
    });

    it('should render a list of upcoming challenges', async () => {
      render(<ChallengePage />, {
        mocks: upcomingFilterMock,
      });

      await waitFor(() => {
        screen.debug();
        // expect(screen.getByTestId('upcoming-challenge')).toBeInTheDocument();
      });
    });
  });
});

When running the last test 'should render a list of upcoming challenges', I get this warning from apollo:
Expected variables: {"filters":[[{"relationship":"challenge","column":"start_at","operator":"lt","value":"2024-04-17T00:00:00.000-04:00"}],[{"relationship":"challenge","column":"end_at","operator":"gt","value":"2024-04-17T00:00:00.000-04:00"}]]}

Failed to match 1 mock for this query. The mocked response had the following variables:
  {"filters":[[{"relationship":"challenge","column":"start_at","operator":"gt","value":"2024-04-17T00:00:00.000-04:00"}]]}

This typically indicates a configuration error in your mocks setup, usually due to a typo or mismatched variable.

The expected variables seem to be activeFilterMock, but not upcomingFilterMock.
Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Every call to render creates a completely new MockProvider than the other MockProviders that have been rendered before, and they have no knowledge of each other. There is no "switching" going on between them. Are you sure you're not passing in a wrong mock somewhere?
